# Is Batman Begins set in the same timeline as Batman, Batman Returns, Batman Forever, and Batman and Robin?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, batman-begins

I know that the movie Batman Begins [2005] was made many years after the movies Batman, Batman Returns, Batman Forever, and Batman and Robin.

If Batman Begins is in the same timeline as the other movies it must be set in a year before all the other movies in the series! However after seeing all the movies I think it is based in a year much later than the other movies.

So is Batman Begins in the same timeline as the previous Batman movies?

Comment: I wish it was. Bale's Batman versus Schwarzenegger's Mr Freeze 

Answer (score 24):

[*Batman Begins*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_begins) has nothing to do with the [original quadrilogy of Batman films](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_in_film#Tim_Burton_.2F_Joel_Schumacher_series). It is a [reboot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot_%28fiction%29), and is only in-universe with *[The Dark Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_%28film%29)* and [*The Dark Knight Rises*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Rises).

From *[Batman Begins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Begins)*' Wikipedia page:

> The film reboots the Batman film series, telling the origin story of
>   the character and begins with Bruce Wayne's initial fear of bats, the
>   death of his parents, and his journey to becoming Batman.

Answer (score 18):

The Burton/Schumacher Batman movies were a separate continuity/universe from the Christopher Nolan movies.

Nolan's movies were a "reboot" of the franchise and character.

In an old [interview with Nolan](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2005/jun/15/features.features11), he explains the studio's mindset.

> "When I was looking for what to do next, one of the things I heard about was that Warner Bros were looking to restart Batman. After the success of Spider-Man, they felt they ought to get their big guys off the bench. **The great part was that they wanted to refresh and invigorate the franchise, but didn't have any specific concepts and were essentially looking for someone to come in and tell them what to do. It's pretty unusual to have this sort of movie up for grabs.**"
>
> (snip)
>
> So what is his take on the material? With the polished ease of a man who has been through a thousand pitch meetings, Nolan explains his idea. "The origin story was the bit that had never been told. I wanted to try to do it in a more realistic fashion than anyone had ever tried to a superhero film before. I talked a lot about films I liked, particularly the 1978 Superman, which is the closest thing to what I proposed. Obviously, some of it is dated, but it's an epic film, with a certain realistic texture. I wanted to make the Batman epic you expected to have been made in 1979."

Christian Bale elaborates on this in [a separate interview](http://www.tribute.ca/magazines/tribute/0405/cover_story.htm)

> Batman Begins isn't a sequel to the Keaton-Kilmer-Clooney films. And despite the title, it's not a prequel.  **It's a complete reboot of the series. "We want you to forget there has ever been a Batman before this one," explains Bale.** "[It's] his early days, the beginnings of Bruce Wayne. So you do see him as a very young boy, and then you see him at age 22, and then you see him again at age 29 or 30. A very large part of the movie is taken up with that before you even see any ears at all."

Comment: A far better answer than the others (based on evidence rather than opinion/the wiki) and worthy of more attention.

Answer (score 8):

No, they are completely separate movie franchises, and interpretations of the Batman mythos.

The Christopher Nolan Batman series was a "reboot" on the Batman movie franchise - it completely disregards/ignores (thankfully) what had come previously in order to tell a new story.

Batman/Batman Returns/Batman Forever/Batman and Robin were one series.
Batman Begins/The Dark Knight/The Dark Knight Rises is a completely separate series.

Answer (score 3):

The movie [Batman Begins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Begins) as well as [The Dark Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_%28film%29) and the upcoming [The Dark Knight Rises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Rises) are all part of the same "series", they are related insofar as they are movies about Batman but are not meant to be contiguous with the others.